# Change language of the gnome shell overview

Tags: language-support, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I noticed that the search results of settings in the gnome shell overview stay in English although my system language is German. I doesn't really disturb me but I'm wondering a bit why this happens. Does anyone have an idea how I can change the language of the search results? When I open them the settings app is opened in German again. Kind of weird I think. Thanks a lot for your help! My gnome version is 3.14.3 on Ubuntu 14.10.

[image: Screenshot of the Gnome Shell Overview - System language is German but the search results of the settings are in English.]

Comment: Filled a bug report under https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+bug/1491787 Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is about the translation of the *gnome-control-center* package. For instance, the info in the "Details" entry is fetched from the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-info-panel.desktop`. So either the strings are not (yet) translated into German, or it's some kind of bug. You may want to [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+filebug) to call the translators' attention to it.